# java application remote debuging from Netbeans to Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, netbeans, raspberry-pi

I use NetBeans under Windows for Java console application; 
I set The Java debugger (JPDA, SocketAttach, dt_socket, Raspberry IP, port, timeout);
But how to send automatically the result of Java generation (the full content of 'dist' folder)  to remote system (Raspberry) in order to debug the last package. 
I search for a "post-generation" script...FTP script, or something else.
Best regards.

Comment: You do that before starting to debug.

Comment: Yes, but where is the area in NetBeans where I can describe the script to execute in order to copy the dist folder ?

Comment: You may need to copy the files manually.

Comment: Ok, I resolve by myself. I develop a small soft which detect change in dist folder and synchronize dist and remote raspberry folder through SshFTP.